# Creating Map Point object in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, mappoint

This code has a run-time error saying object required on this line...

```
Set objDataSets = objApp.ActiveMap.DataSets
```

This is what I used as a reference...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa723407.aspx

---

```
Sub CreateMaps()

Dim MPApp As MapPoint.Application
Set MPApp = New MapPoint.Application

MPApp.Visible = True
MPApp.UserControl = True

OpenDataSet

End Sub

Sub OpenDataSet()

Dim objDataSets As MapPoint.DataSets
Dim objDataSet As MapPoint.DataSet
Dim zDataSource As String

zDataSource = "S:\Projects\StateMapData.xlsx!Data!AY5:AZ56"
Set objDataSets = objApp.ActiveMap.DataSets
Set objDataSet = objDataSets.ImportData(zDataSource)

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to set `objApp`.  Per the page you linked to: "Note  This and other samples in this topic assume that MapPoint is already running, and that objApp is a MapPoint Application object that has already been initialized."

Comment: So my MPApp is the objApp in the OpenDataSet procedure.

Comment: Right, so I'd replace objApp with MPApp in the `Set objDataSets` line.

Comment: Ok so now I'm getting a Run-time error '4007' Cannot connect with the specified DataSourceMoniker.  Any idea what that's about?

Comment: Got that error figured out.  Now on to customizing the maps.